# Binomial Random variable to prove to expression

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-distribution

> Consider a binomial random variable $X\sim\operatorname{Binom}(n,\theta)$.
>
> 1. Show that $f_X(x+1)=f_X(x)\left(\frac{n-x}{x+1}×\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\right)$.
> 2. Show that $f_X(x+1)>f_X(x)$ iff $x<(n+1)\theta-1$.

I can get $f_X(x)$ and $f_X(x+1)$ as below but how to solve question 1 and 2?
$$f_X(x)=\binom nx\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$$
$$f_X(x+1)=\binom n{x+1}\theta^{x+1}(1-\theta)^{n-(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (1), compute $$\frac{f_X(x+1)}{f_X(x)}.$$  For part (2), use the result from part (1) to determine when this ratio exceeds $1$.

Comment: One more check, using part(3), find the maximum value of p(x) if n=10, ∅=0.1.  Any idea ?

Comment: @SimonLeung No.  Show your own effort.  I've given you everything you need to answer the question.  This is not a homework answering service.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SJrGDwC-PfNAj9PYG9A4OypwgpG8xD0X/view?usp=sharing

My ans is 0.372 but the correct ans should be 0.3874. Do I miss anything ?

Comment: @SimonLeung Because $X$ is a binomial random variable, it can only take on integer values between $0$ and $n$, inclusive.  So you solved the inequality condition and got $x = 0.1$, but then without thinking, you calculated $\Pr[X = 0.1]$ using the formula, but the formula doesn't apply when $x$ is not integer.  Instead, what the inequality tells you is that $f_X(x) < f_X(x+1)$ when $x < 0.1$, so that means $\Pr[X = 0] < \Pr[X = 1]$, but $\Pr[X = 1] > \Pr[X = 2]$.  Thus $f_X(x)$ attains its maximum at $x = 1$, and you need to calculate $\Pr[X = 1]$.

Comment: Great Thx. Got it !